# AngularJS not updating, directive in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui

I have this quiz AngularJS app where I have 2 types of questions:

1. **Simple** - where you need to choose 1 or 2 choices to answer the question and go to the next question.
2. **Range Slider** - where you need to drag a range slider, when the user is stop dragging, I'm validating the answers and go to the next question.

I'm displaying the current question using ng-if (current $index = $scope.currentQuestion and I'm incremeting by one everytime a question in answered).

On the simple question everything works as exepted but on the **Range Slider questions** after the user is stoping dragging, there is a 1-2s delay before its displaying the next question.

**I need to click again somewhere on the page to see the next question.**

Can someone explain me why its not updating instant like the simple question and why this delay occurs?

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.currentQuestion = 0;

  $scope.isCurrentQuestion = function(index) {
    return $scope.currentQuestion === index
  };

  $scope.$on('question:answered', function(event, data) {
    $scope.currentQuestion = data.current;
  });

  $scope.questions = [{
    'title': 'test #1',
    'type': 1,
    'choices': ['Choice #1', 'Choice #2', 'Choice #3', 'Choice #4'],
    // othe stuff
  }, {
    'title': 'test #2',
    'type': 2
      // othe stuff
  }, {
    'title': 'test #3',
    'type': 2
      // othe stuff
  }];

})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/EiymOBRcpxoDQQlnHjqV?p=preview

Btw. I'm using https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-slider this directive for the range slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kinds of bugs are usually caused by not calling `$scope.$apply()` at the appropriate time. It seems the `stop()` callback is not calling `$apply`, changing your code to:

```
    function stop(event, ui) {
      scope.$apply(function() {
        scope.value = ui.value;
        validate(scope.value);
      });
    }
```

... seems to correct this behaviour: [Forked plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/0AtgREmDaWnfpat8sZMF?p=preview)